# change column names based on matched names

Tags: r

I would like to replace the column names in `dt2` by searching for matching names in `col_name_dt1` then repplace it with what is in `col_name_masked`. I figured i could use the `match` commad somehow?

```
> col_name_dt1
   col_name col_name_masked
1      1_JH               1
2   107_MAE               4
3   108_IME               3
4    109_GW               2

> colnames(dt2)
 [1] "1_JH"     "107_MAE"  "108_IME"   "109_GW"
```

Note: `col_name_dt1` contains more names than is found in `dt2`. The length of `dt2` is 62 whereas `dim(col_name_dt1)` is 96.

output

```
> colnames(dt2)
 [1] "1"     "4"  "3"   "2"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
col_name_dt1$col_name_masked[match(colnames(dt2), col_name_dt1$col_name)]

#[1] 1 4 3 2
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to say that the length of the two df is not the same, this creates some NAs. See update

Comment: In that case, just reverse the order in `match`. See update.